# SqlDataReader Execution error

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

i m trying to retrieve the Specialization ID from a table called Specializationtbl, using C# MSVS 2008 and the table includes SpecializationName and SpecializationID beside some other rows and my question is related to some error " No Data to present ", the command goes as bellow:

```
SqlCommand READSpecID = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Specializationtbl WHERE SpecializationName='" + comboBox1.Text + "'" , DBcnction);
DBcnction.Open();

SqlDataReader ReadSpecID_ = READSpecID.ExecuteReader();
ReadSpecID_.Read();
int SpecID_ = Convert.ToInt16(ReadSpecID_["SpecID"].ToString());

DBcnction.Close();
```

i also tried to Select the "SpecID" instead of all the rows, but cant seem to seal the query correctly and keep receiving "No data present " error, any idea where am i making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Try opening DBcnction before assigning the value to READSPecID

```
DBcnction.Open();
SqlCommand READSpecID = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Specializationtbl WHERE     SpecializationName='" + comboBox1.Text + "'" , DBcnction);
```

2)  Run the command in SSMS:

```
 SELECT * FROM Specializationtbl WHERE SpecializationName ='yourvalue'
```

and see  if any results are returned

3) Check comboBox1.Text has a value in it

4) Validate the contents of comboBox1.Text (Or use paremetrised queries or a stored procedure) to ensure you do not become a victim of SQL Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

Refactor to solve your TWO problems:

1. Your SQL injection problem when building your SQL statement.
2. Use ExecuteScalar if you only need one value.
3. Implement `using` blocks.

```
 string retVal;        
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
 using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
 {
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SpecID FROM Specializationtbl WHERE SpecializationName= @Name";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", comboBox1.Text);
   conn.Open();
   retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
int specID = int.Parse(retVal);
```

If you really needed more than one value from your statement:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
 using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
 {
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SpecID, Value2 FROM Specializationtbl WHERE SpecializationName= @Name";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", comboBox1.Text);
   conn.Open();
   var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      Customer c = new Customer { 
             ID = dr["SpecID"].ToString(),
             Value = dr["Value2"].ToString(),
       };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to first test if there are any rows.  I suspect the query is returning zero rows.

if (ReadSpecID_.HasRows)
   {
       ReadSpecID_.Read();
   }